# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest' com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException

Tags: flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 2; The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

Trying to run emulator device for flutter file downloader but facing this error even chat gpt is not providing a clear answer